# Como saber se uma porta está aberta ou não no Linux

Tags: linux, terminal

Tenho um script PHP que atua como servidor de um chat (websocket) que tenho num determinado sistema. Percebo que as vezes inesperadamente esse serviço para de rodar. Ele é executado através do comando `nohup`.

Estou usando Linux.

Só percebo que o script do meu websocket para de funcionar quando vejo o erro do navegador:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://myserver:9001/chat' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Bem, eu gostaria de saber detectar se realmente o meu script do servidor websocket parou de rodar, pois não sei se o erro do navegador sempre quer dizer que meu servidor "caiu".

Então, como é que posso detectar se determinada porta está em uso ou não?

Qual comando no `Linux` posso utilizar pra saber se uma porta está aberta ou não?

Comment: Essa pergunta me interessa tambem, para o **OpenSuse**.

Comment: embora seja fora de contexto segue 
nmap -sT -O localhost

Comment: Você quer detectar dentro de um script em alguma linguagem específica ou quer usar o terminal linux para tal detecção?

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu quero usar o Terminal. Pois assim eu saberia se o script realmente parou de rodar ou não. O navegador pode ter outros problemas que acusem como erro.

Comment: @Otto fora de contexto? O Linux é o Sistema operacional que eu utilizo no meu servidor. Acho que falar de servidor ou do SO que ele usa aqui não é fora de contexto.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters mas efetivamente não seria sobre programação, posso estar enganado mas é fora de contexto sim

Comment: De qualquer forma, o @Otto já respondeu à pergunta. Só tenho a adicionar que se quiser testar (de um ponto fora do servidor) se a porta está disponível em TCP, você pode usar `telnet meudominio.com 443` (onde 443 é o número da sua porta).

Comment: A sua pergunta parece estar [fora do nosso escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Mas felizmente a rede [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) conta com o site [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) que é um Q&A voltado para usuários de sistemas Unix like. Se preferir você pode encaminhar sua pergunta a essa comunidade, lembrando que é um comunidade independente da nossa que portanto possui suas próprias regras é gerida em língua inglesa.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A forma mais simples para verificar isto seria usando o comando:

```
nmap -sT -O localhost
```

Como adicionado pelo Marco pode ser testado de um ponto externo:

```
telnet meudominio.com 443 (onde 443 é o número da sua porta)
```

Existe uma opção também seria utilizar o netstat:

```
# netstat -tl - lista as conexões abertas de tcp em modo de escuta
# netstat -t - lista as conexões tcp estabelecidas
# netstat -p - lista os programas que estão usando a conexão
# netstat --numeric-ports - não converte o número da porta para ser listado
# netstat --numeric-hosts - não converte o número de ip para nome do host 

# netstat -t -l -p --numeric-ports
```

Ou ainda:

```
lsof -i tcp
```

Comment: No primeiro caso, eu teria que instalar o `nmap`. O servidor é semi-dedicado (não tenho acesso ao root, sniff) :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters editei a resposta, talvez assim te ajude.

Comment: O `netstat -tl` funcionou certinho. Valeu :D